# How to prevent Excel from prompting user to enable macros?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with an Excel purchase-order generator that has two worksheets: a PO-generator (sheet1) and details for a drop down validation list on the PO (sheet2).  There is code in the `ThisWorkbook` code module.

The PO generator works by increment PO number, copy/pasting, saving and re-saving with a new file name.

I am struggling to incorporate a way of prompting users to ensure macros are enabled and prevent the generator (`Sheet1`) being otherwise seen.

I have included a routine to delete all vba code on the generated purchase orders (and no code or modules being present on them), yet they re-open with a macro security warning.

---

My code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        MsgBox "Please use dropdown arrow next to filename " & _
            "within SharePoint and select " & _
            "'Edit in Microsoft Office Excel' instead."
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("U13") = Range("U13") + 1
    Workbooks.Open Filename := _
        "\\ehfnp01\users\gminter\My Documents\PO Log Elite\PO Log Elite.xls"
    Workbooks("PO Log Elite.xls").Activate
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Unprotect Password:="2"
    End With
    Workbooks("Elite Purchase Order Generator Ver 7 20-12-13.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("U13").Copy
    Workbooks("PO Log Elite.xls").Activate
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Dim lst As Long
        lst = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("B" & lst).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    End With
    Workbooks("Elite Purchase Order Generator Ver 7 20-12-13.xls").Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Workbooks("PO Log Elite.xls").Activate
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lst = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & lst) = Now
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        lst = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("C" & lst).Value = Environ("Username")
        .Protect Password:="2"
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ThisFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & _
        Range("T13").Value & Range("U13").Text & ".xls"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile, Password:=""
    Range("U14") = Now
    Range("L21").Value = Environ("Username")
    Set Rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("L21"))
    For Each C In Rng
        C.Value = StrConv(C.Value, vbUpperCase)
    Next
    Cells.Locked = False
    Range("U13:Y14,L21:Z21,A79:AE144").Locked = True
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="1"
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MacroEnable").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    Dim x               As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        For x = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            .VBComponents.Remove .VBComponents(x)
        Next x
        For x = .VBComponents.Count To 1 Step -1
            .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.DeleteLines _
            1, .VBComponents(x).CodeModule.CountOfLines
        Next x
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The best way I know is to hide the sheets that requires macros and only make it possible to unhide them using macros (as a Workbook_Open event for example).

Answer (score 0):

So if I've understood, you want the Excel file generated by the PO generator to save down so that opening it does not trigger the macro warning pop-up bar.

To get this to work:

1. you need to remove all code from your worksheet ***and remove each `Module` object*** from the Visual Basic Editor (in the `Developer` ribbon).  Note that unless you actually `Remove...` each Module object (select & right-click in the VB editor), Excel will continue to display the warning bar.  Saving it after these removals will prevent the Macro warning...
2. Another item to check is whether you have any **External Data Connections**.  If you do, there may still be a warning that pops up prompting user whether to activate these.  To get rid of these, got to `Data` ribbon `> Connections` and remove any connections one by one.
3. Remember to save the file to the standard **`.xlsx`** format (Excel Workbook) instead of the default `.xlsm` for worksheets with macros (Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook).

Any buttons or other UI features can be left in as long as there is no code.